# Bootstrap hamburger menu changing position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[How do I prevent this from happening](https://gyazo.com/13fff055d0502a05cb0c8cb264630422)

I want the hamburger icon to stay to the right, what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/amtrbsk2/

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg text-nowrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row w-100 align-items-center">

        <div class="col col-lg-3">
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand justify-content-start">
                <h1 class="display-3" id="cont">Yrkeskock<span id="se">.SE</span></h1>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-lg-5">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Hem</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Recept</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Arbetssökande</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Omdömen</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Hjälpmedel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-lg-1"></div>

        <div class="col col-lg-3">
            <div class="navbar-nav collapse navbar-collapse navbar1">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link mx-1" id="login"><i class="fas fa-user-check mr-1"></i>Logga In</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link mx-1"><i class="fas fa-user-plus mr-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="hamburger" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar1"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button></nav>
```

Comment: you want hamburger on top always or drop-down list?

Comment: The `a` and `i` tags near the end of your code never close, causing the closing `</div>` tags after them not to be recognised. Fix this by adding `</i></a>` after `<a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link mx-1"><i class="fas fa-user-plus mr-1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove Class **container** from `14 line in jsfiddle`.

Your code should then look like this:

`<div class="">`

`<div class="row w-100 align-items-center">`

Instead Of:

`<div class="container">`

`<div class="row w-100 align-items-center">`

*`container` class consist of `width:100%` which is breaking navbar flex.*

Comment: Thank's! It works as it should now but I have to reposition everything, why is it a problem with having it in a container? Sorry I'm new and trying to understand how it works

Comment: @Chrissebe it is happening because container has an inbuild CSS which is wrecking the CSS of parent `navbar` class. `container` class consist of property `width: 100%` which is breaking your navbar flex.

Comment: @Chrissebe feel free to ask anything. Happy Coding.